# Unable to display MySQL table data using Razor (and/or .NET)

Tags: .net, mysql, razor

I've imported a table into a MySQL database and I want to display the data on a webpage, creating an ordered list from the data entries.

I'm using Razor (and/or .NET) in the CMS Umbraco but unfortunately for me I'm not able to use Gridview or WebMatrix. [This article from the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg548376%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) shows exactly what I'd like to do, but I'm having problems on creating an alternative script.

My code so far:

```
@{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=database;user id=username;password=password");
   SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM entries", con);

   con.Open();

   MySqlCommand db = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

   foreach(var row in db.Query(sql)) {
     <ul>
       <li>@row.Name - @row.Description</li>
     </ul>
   }

   if(con != null){
     con.Close();
   }
}
```

With this code I get the error "The best overloaded method match for "*MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.MySqlCommand(string, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments"*, which sounds to me like I'm way off with my current code, how can I display the table data easily, without using WebMatrix?

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is saying
"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.MySqlCommand(string, MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection)' has some invalid arguments"

That means that you are "calling" wrong the MySqlCommand, instead of calling the method with  a string an mysqlconnection parameter, you're calling the method with a sqlcommand and a sqlconnection.

There is an example in the [mysql page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executereader)

```
public void CreateMySqlDataReader(string mySelectQuery, MySqlConnection myConnection) 
 {
    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
      while(myReader.Read()) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      myReader.Close();
      myConnection.Close();
    }
 }
```